# Use of setreuid() where _POSIX_SAVED_IDS is not set

Tags: c, linux, permissions, suid

I am exploring the suid area, and found myself unable to answer this question. For the sake of the question, lets assume the program binary is suid, owned by user 1001 and ran by user 1000 (both *non-root*) - therefor RUID=1000, EUID=1001.

When `_POSIX_SAVED_IDS` is set, I can use `setuid()` and `seteuid()` in order to change the RUID and EUID (respectively) between 1000 and 1001.

However, when `_POSIX_SAVED_IDS` is not set, `seteuid(1000)` will render doing `seteuid(1001)` impossible later, and `setuid(1001)` will do the same to `setuid(1000)` later on.

In order to change the EUID to the RUID and keep the possibility of going back later on, the solution I found here [GNU Setuid Program Example](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html) is to use `setreuid(1001,1000)` (swapping them). What are the effects of this on the program, since it changes the RUID? From what I understand, it changes the owner of the process, and therefor has implications on permissions of killing or interacting with the process.
What systems do not use _POSIX_SAVED_IDS?

Answer (score 1):

Since POSIX requires `_POSIX_SAVED_IDS` to be defined with positive value, no systems should lack `_POSIX_SAVED_IDS`.

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html

Comment: except, of course, those that make no claims to POSIX compliance, which is what the OPs final question was...

Comment: I thought it was just a matter that saved ids *used to* be optional, but were later made mandatory. I doubt there are still systems without saved ids, unless you could very outdated versions, in which case they're probably full of vulnerabilities and not very practical to be using...

Comment: That may be the history, but if a system doesn't claim to be POSIX compliant, then it has no obligation to implement _POSIX_ANYTHING... Of course most *nix-en these days are POSIX compliant. Not sure about Windows variants, they definitely weren't in the past, I know...

Comment: [Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setuid.html) it says in the bottom "The functionality associated with _POSIX_SAVED_IDS is now mandatory. This is a FIPS requirement."  

The only OS I found without it is FreeBSD prior to roughly 2001.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with this and the part below is not properly answered so far.

> In order to change the EUID to the RUID and keep the possibility of going back later on, the solution I found here GNU Setuid Program Example is to use setreuid(1001,1000) (swapping them). What are the effects of this on the program, since it changes the RUID? From what I understand, it changes the owner of the process, and therefor has implications on permissions of killing or interacting with the process.

what happens everywhere, is that the EUID is the only thing that's used for permissions like accessing files or being able to kill processes (some rare exceptions might apply).
The idea is that you can switch back and forth between the EUID and RUID, but *only* between those. The Kernel needs to keep track of those two ids.

`seteuid` for non-root users is only allowed to switch to one of EUID, RUID and - should the kernel support it - SUID.

With a system being conform with POSIX, a SUID is avaliable, so this will happen:

```
// uids are: EUID=1001, RUID=1000, SUID=1001
seteuid(1000) ; // works because RUID=1000
// uids are: EUID=1000, RUID=1000, SUID=1001
seteuid(1001); // works because SUID=1001
```

on systems without a SUID:

```
// uids are: EUID=1001, RUID=1000
seteuid(1000); // works because RUID=1000
// uids are: EUID=1000, RUID=1000
seteuid(1001); // fails, neither EUID, nor RUID is 1001
```

conversely

```
// uids are: EUID=1001, RUID=1000
setreuid(1001, 1000) ; // works because EUID=1001 and RUID=1000
// uids are: EUID=1000, RUID=1001
setreuid(1000, 1001); // works because EUID=1000 and RUID=1001
```

I have not found a standard way of permanently dropping privileges on a POSIX conform system, as this required modifying the SUID. only a gnu extension is avaliable:

```
// uids are: EUID=1001, RUID=1000, SUID=1001
setresuid(1000, 1000, 1000);
// uids are: EUID=1000, RUID=1000, SUID=1000
```

see: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf